# CSS: nav sprite image alignment problems

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-sprites

Here is my dev link:
http://leongaban.com/dev/just_nav.html

I'm having issues with Text alignment and Sprite alignment. This is the [css sprite tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) I am working from.

What I don't understand is why are the li's different widths, I looked in Chrome's inspector and currently the first nav button's width is *190* and the 2nd is *215*.

It seems to be based on the text inside of the li's. How would I go about correctly creating 4 nav buttons with a size of *196 x 60* with 2 pixels in between the 1st & 2nd and 3rd and 4th?

**Any tips welcomed!**

Current CSS:

```
.nav {
width: 790px;
height: 60px;
}

#nav { width: 790px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;}

#nav ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#nav li {
width: 196px;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
color: white;
}

#nav li a {
background-image:url('../img/sprite_nav.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
height: 60px;
padding: 0px 2px 32px 100px;
}

#nav li a.item1 {background-position:0px 0px; }
#nav li a:hover.item1 {background-position:0px -60px; }
#nav li a:active.item1 {background-position:0px -120px; }

#nav li a.item2 {background-position:0px 0px; }
#nav li a:hover.item2 {background-position:0px -60px; }
#nav li a:active.item2 {background-position:0px -120px; }

#nav li a.item3 {background-position:0px 0px; }
#nav li a:hover.item3 {background-position:0px -60px; }
#nav li a:active.item3 {background-position:0px -120px; }

#nav li a.item4 {background-position:0px 0px; }
#nav li a:hover.item4 {background-position:0px -60px; }
#nav li a:active.item4 {background-position:0px -120px; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#nav li a {
background-image:url('../img/sprite_nav.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
height: 45px;
width: 190px;
display: block;
float: left;
padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My padding was way off

Comment: No prob! I'd recommend looking into how the box model is interpreted and that will prevent this sort of thing from happening moving forward.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few problems there. First, put all your markup in `<a>` instead of `<li>`. And `float: left` your `<li>`s instead of `display: inline`. Also `<a>` should be `display: block` and `height` and `line-height` must be the same to center text vertically. Also `list-style-type` goes in `<ul>` rather than `<li>`. I've no real way to try this but it should work.

```
#nav ul { list-display-type: none; }
#nav li { float: left; }
#nav a { 
    display: block;
    width: 196px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    /* The rest of styles */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a padding that is **0px 2px 32px 100px** on the **a**'s elements

```
<a class="item2" href="#" title="View Interactive">Interactive</a>
```

I would suggest you trying the following css call

```
 #nav li a {
   background-image:url('../img/sprite_nav.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   color: white;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 30px;
   height: 60px;
   padding: 32px 0;
   width: 196px;
   display: block;
   float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

"4 nav buttons with a size of 196 x 60 with 2 pixels in between the 1st & 2nd and 3rd and 4th"

For us to give good advice, please put your code up on jsfiddle.net and send us the link so we can help test. But from the top of my head I can add:

1. To display the list items horizontally, and setting the dimensions to 196 x 60, set the to display: block, float: left... and set the height and width. Add text-align: center so it'll center text.
2. To make the text center vertically too, I think you need to set the line-height to the inner height of the li element, and then add vertical-align: middle too.

We'll be able to help better if your code is available to see and test on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ah jsfiddle... will definitely use it from now on :)